# empty() and alisasing - PHP

Tags: php

[Big edit, the question is better in this way]

I would like to find a shortcut (without NOTICE) for this code :

```
if( !empty( $long_var['with']['useless']['long']['argument'] ) )
    $long_var['with']['useless']['long']['argument'] = 
        Custom::myParsing($long_var['with']['useless']['long']['argument']);
```

As you can see I've got a long var to process, and I don't want to bring it around... (as it's not an isolate case in my code, I want something "clean")

For now I use this :

```
if( !empty( $long_var['with']['useless']['long']['argument'] ) ){
    $lnArgument = &$long_var['with']['useless']['long']['argument'];
    $lnArgument = Custom::myParsing($lnArgument);
}
```

This could be the best, but it bring back a Error before php5.5 and a Notice after :

```
if( !empty( $lnArgument = &$long_var['with']['useless']['long']['argument'] ) )
    $lnArgument = Custom::myParsing($lnArgument);
```

Comment: Why would you doing this ? That's a very weird syntax .

Comment: Its not weird, I use a framework that bring me back var with an average of 4 to 5 deep, so it's really long and ugly yo use around. as I have to make an empty test on the var to know if I'll have to run my custom function on it, making an alias that'll be easy to understand in the if block seem better/cleaner for me. (just try to read the top block and the 2 bottom one...)

Comment: @Raptor I've updated to be closer of what I face (the last block at the bottom is the "classic way" )

Comment: Lomg time php programmer and never needed empty ()

Comment: @Jack empty is the base function when you work with http protocol : as you can't have `NULL` or `FALSE` nor `INT 0`, you have to check for empty string and lookalike, isset is useless for this, but !empty allow you to check `isset && !=="" && !=="0"` so it'll bring you a bool false for every false equivalent value

Comment: @Blag why don't you let php interpreter eval your variable as boolean when needed? Is there any case it evaluates the variable with a different value than !empty ()?

Comment: @Jack my var may not exist so I check this before (I'm against Notice), and that lead to this : `if(isset($a) and $a)` so using  `if(!empty($a))` is shorter

Comment: @Blag fine. I always quiet down Notice. That's why I never needed empty ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the use of checking `empty` in an assignation, even with PHP 5.5? You are assigning something (maybe a NULL, because the expression does not exist and you also got a `NOTICE: undefined index`) to a variable. You are defining that variable and then checking for empty? Do you know what 'empty' means when checking a variable? First checks if the variable exists and then checks whether that variable equals FALSE. In your case, the variable will **always** exist (you created it just there). So, you are actually only checking if that variable equals FALSE.

tl;dr:

You can safely replace the empty with a simple assignation, and let the `if` find if what was assigned equals FALSE or not:

```
if( $lnArgument = &$long_var['with']['useless']['long']['argument'] )
    $lnArgument = Custom::myParsing($lnArgument);
```

(and you will get Notices, but you already know that)

Comment: ok, my question was not clear, I'll delete it I think; it was more about how to make the shortest code without NOTICE. As it seem the way I try with empty raise one too (I don't know why it seem to not on my first test u_u, as it's logic on the assignation)

Comment: Ok, As you got a +1, I'll not delete, but I've make a big edit on my post, take a look